# sum of the x's and the sample mean issues

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

Quick simple question as I must have missed the explanation. why $$\sum_{j=1}^n (x_j - \bar{x}) = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j - n\bar{x} = (n\bar{x}- n\bar{x})$$

I understand why $\bar{x}$ turns out to be $n\bar{x}$ but i do not get how $x_j$ turns out to  be $n\bar{x}$? This questions comes from trying to study the distribution of the MLE of $\beta$ in a single variate linear regression.

Comment: How would you write the mean as a sum?

Comment: I have removed the generalized-linear-models tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition,

$$
\bar x = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j}{n}
$$

So multiplying through by $n$ yields the result that $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = n\bar x$.